# Invalid Toolchain. Itunes store operation failed

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

As soon as I updated xcode to 9.2 , I cannot validate my archived builds. I get this error message every time:

> Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, macOS, and iOS SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta software including beta macOS builds.

Is this something wrong with Apple's new relase of xcode? Otherwise, I didn't change anything that would make this project using "Beta software".

Comment: ^ The accepted answer in this thread worked. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have faced this too. Apple has just released the Xcode 9.2 update and might not have updated iTunes connect to accept builds from it yet. It might be resolved soon in a couple of hours or days.

Comment: I thought so...

Comment: oh that's great

Comment: that's terrible

Comment: Any idea when it will be fixed. I am waiting for too long to upload my app.

Comment: It is fixed now. I am able to upload.

Answer (score 2):

Download Xcode 9.1 from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

After extracting the .xip, rename it as Xcode-9.1.app (or whatever you want), then drag it into your Applications folder. Xcode.app and Xcode-9.1.app can co-exist in the same folder, and can both run at the same time if you want.

Build your app with Xcode 9.1 and continue to do regular development with Xcode 9.2. At some point, iTunesConnect will start accepting builds made with Xcode 9.2, at which time you can delete Xcode-9.1.app.

Comment: You can test if submission will work using the "Validate..." button when viewing your archives. I kept uploading just to be rejected and continually increasing the build number. The Validate option will save that step.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Seems like Apple resolved the issue! I just uploaded a build with 9.2.

I'm having the same issue. Changing the toolchain setting did not help.
Downloading Xcode 9.1 now but I'm not happy with that solution. Not sure how differently the app would be behave after testing it with 9.2.

Comment: Am also going for that. Did you uninstall the xcode9.2 and then install 9.1 or just straight forward installation over the previous version

Comment: This is not an urgent issue for me. I'm waiting until they flip the right bit. I'm sure they are getting an earful.

Comment: Download Xcode 9.1 from the developer portal, you can have multiple version in parallel just make sure you only have one open at a time.

Answer (score -1):

From Xcode -> Go to Organizer -> Under Archives, select the build and right click to Show in finder -> Select the Project and right click to -> Show Package Contents -> Double click on Info.plist and add a row. The key is  BuildMachineOSBuild and the Type is String and the Value is 16G29 (Value is based on your Mac OS Version. Please follow the below given link)

https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201260   [.....Check the version number for your Mac OS version and set the value in the Info.plist](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201260)

For example if your Mac OS version is 10.12.6 then add this to your plist

```
<key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
<string>16G29</string>
```

You are ready to send your build to iTunes Connect